# Why the form submitted using AJAX is redirecting to next page and the error/success messages are not displayed into alert on the same page?

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, form-submit

I'm using PHP, Smarty, jQuery, AJAX, etc. for my website.Following is HTML code of my form which I'm submitting using AJAX:

```
<form name="question_issue_form" id="question_issue_form" action="http://localhost/xyz/pqr/web/control/modules/questions/question_issue.php">
      <input type="hidden" name="form_submitted" id="form_submitted" value="yes"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="op" id="op" value="question_issue"/>
      <input type="hidden" name="question_id" id="question_id" value="35718"/>

      <table class="trnsction_details" width="100%" cellpadding="5">
        <tbody>    
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td>
              <input type="checkbox" name = "que_issue[]" value = "Question is wrong" id ="chkQueWrong">Question is wrong</input>
            </td>
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name = "que_issue[]" value = "Answers are wrong" id ="chkAnsWrong">Answers are wrong</input></td> 
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name = "que_issue[]" value = "Question direction is incorrect" id ="chkDirIncorrect">Question direction is incorrecct</input></td>                
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="checkbox" name = "que_issue[]" value = "Other" id ="chkOther">Other</input></td>          
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td class="set_message" style="display:none;"><textarea name="que_issue_comment" id = "que_issue_comment" rows="4" cols="25" maxlength="100"></textarea></td>      
          </tr>
          <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit" id="report_question_issue" class="c-btn submit_form"/></td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </form>
```

The AJAX code for submitting the form is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$('#question_issue_form').submit(function() {
var ans = confirm("Are you sure to report the question issue?");
    if (!ans) { 
      return false;
    }
var post_url = $(this).attr('action');
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: post_url,
        data: $('#question_issue_form').serialize(),
        dataType: 'json',
        success: function(data) { alert(data);
          var error = data.error_message;
          if(error)
            alert(error);
          else {
            alert("Question issue has been reported successfully.");
            $.colorbox.close();
          }
        }
      });
    });
  });
```

The PHP code of a file(question_issue.php) where I'm submitting this form is as follows:

```
<?php 
  require_once("../../includes/application-header.php");

  $objQuestionIssue = new QuestionIssue(); 

  prepare_request();
  $request = $_POST ;
$user_type = $_SESSION[SESSION_NAME_CONTROL][STAFF_TYPE];

  if($user_type == 'super_admin' || $user_type == 'admin' || $user_type == 'data_entry_operator' || $user_type == 'owner' || $user_type == 'faculty' || $user_type == 'content_development_head' || $user_type == 'test_admin' || $user_type == 'student_admin')
    $requested_user_type = 'staff';
  else       
    $requested_user_type = 'student';

    $form_data = array();
    $form_data['question_id']        = $request['question_id'];
    $form_data['reported_site_id']   = SITE_ID;
    $form_data['reported_user_type'] = $requested_user_type;
    $form_data['reported_user_id']   = $_SESSION[SESSION_NAME_CONTROL][STAFF_ID];
    $form_data['que_issue']          = implode(",", $request['que_issue']);
    $form_data['que_issue_comment']  = $request['que_issue_comment'];
    $form_data['que_issue_date']     = time();
switch( $op ) { 
        case "question_issue":
          if($request['form_submitted']=='yes') {
                $ret = $objQuestionIssue->InsertQuetionIssue($form_data, $question_issue_error_messages);
                /*If condition : If there are any errors in submission of a report question form*/
                if(!$ret) {
                    $error_msg  = $objQuestionIssue->GetAllErrors();
                    $data = array();
                    $data['error_message'] = $error_msg['error_msgs'];
                    $data = json_encode($data);
                    echo $data;
                    die;
                /*Else condition : If there is no error in submission of a report question form*/   
                } else {
                    $data = array();
                    $data['success_message'] = "success";
                    $data = json_encode($data);
                    echo $data;
                    die;
                }
            } else {
                  $smarty->assign('question_id', $request['question_id']);
                  $file_to_show = 'question-issue.tpl';
                }           
                $smarty->display($file_to_show);
            break;  
            die;
  }  
?>
```

The issue I'm facing is when I click on Ok button of confirmation alert, the form gets submit but the error messages or success messages in json format are appearing on a blank screen.

Actually they should be appeared in a pop-up alert and page should not get redirected to other URL. But the error/success messages are printing on a blank white page and page is also redirected to the question_issue.php. Can someone please help me in avoiding these things and showing the error/success messages into an alert box on the same page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should prevent default behavior of the form, so it won't really submit but only ask for json:

```
$('#question_issue_form').submit(function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();
    // your code
```

Comment: I tried your trick. It's working but before displaying the error/success alert message the alert message appears "[object Object]" with Ok button. What's this and how to avoid this?

Comment: @PHPLover You have an `alert(data);` in your code. That's what's probably showing you the object returned from the PHP.

Comment: It's because `data` is JSON object. It's like you were trying to alert an array instead of string. You probably want to access certain property.

Comment: Yeah, it was my mistake. Thanks for correcting it though. Your answer has been accepted and upvoted too. Cheers!!!